# Which are the most expensive LEGO sets?

Tags: sets

Which is the most expensive LEGO set at sale price?

And which one is the most expensive ever sold, even considering old ones at auction?

Answer (score 5):

The most expensive (and second largest) LEGO set to date is the #10179 LEGO Star Wars Millennium Falcon released in 2007, with 5,195 pieces, and the cost of $500. Equally expensive (also $500), but much smaller is the recently released #75159 LEGO Star Wars Death Star with 4,016 pieces.

As far as what is the most someone paid for a LEGO set in a private transaction would be impossible to tell. You could use the BrickLink Price Guide for prices sets sold for in the last six months, and you can also do something similar for eBay, but there are many other places people buy and sell LEGO (social-media sites, forums, commercial websites, auction sites, and more). You would really have to narrow down what data you are looking for, and go from there.

Comment: @TheBrickBloccker I guess I should also check at auction houses for vintage LEGO sets from the '50s...

Comment: Surprisingly, older LEGO sets do not always equate to higher sales prices. Yes, rare VW buses from the early days of LEGO, especially in unusual prints, can fetch a high price, but most standard LEGO stuff is not worth a big premium if it's 40-50 years old.

Answer (score 1):

In 2017 the $500 2007 UCS Millennium Falcon was surpassed by...

[image]

... [an $800 UCS Millennium Falcon numbered 75192](https://brickset.com/sets/75192-1/Millennium-Falcon), which is currently still available.